# Google Sheet Query + Countif + Condition Question

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to populate how many counts that the company appeared on specific week of the month and I'm having difficulty for that. I'm sorry.

I want to populate how many times each companies occurred or counted depending on the week chosen in the dashboard sheet. I'm sorry english is not my first language.

I use query formula to list and count each companies but when changing the week it does not factor my query I'm unsure what to do.

I was able to do array formula on the right part of the sheet once you've checked the link below but I think it will factor out if 2 companies have the same highest count as it will only output 1 text which is why I have thought of using query to list all companies and how many times they count depending on week chosen but seems the query that I have inputted populates all the data that is in the Dashboard sheet.

I hope someone can help me.

Here is my demo sheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zMoWww9sGxyIC7LLJWBsNRMXN8a7mme1RCT2_IYIXCM/edit#gid=1696267131

Comment: Consider providing input and expected output as **plain text table** in the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easy to copy/paste**.  Avoid sharing [links like spreadsheets](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455), which make the question useless for others or [images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551), which are hard to copy. Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. You just need to add week column in `where` clause. I have added that to your sheet. Try this-

```
=QUERY(Database!$B:$F,"select B, count(B) 
where F=" & C5 &" 
group by B 
order by count(B) DESC 
label B 'List of Companies', count(B) 'Counts'",-1)
```

[image]

Comment: I'm that closee! Thank you it seems at the time I'm doing it I was procrastinating too much. Thank you so much!

Comment: @PorkyGuy Good. If it helps then please consider accepting the answer (tick mark it) to treat the answer as solved.